# ConcurrentModificationException thrown while flushing changes to database

Tags: java, hibernate

I have defined a `@PostUpdate` and a `@PostPersist` entity listener for a couple of methods that result in a data change on the local database.

However, a `ConcurrentModificationException` is thrown while Hibernate is trying to flush the changes into the database. More specifically, the exception occurs while it is persisting new "collections" (*i.e.* one-to-many entities).

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.checkForComodification(AbstractList.java:372)
at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.next(AbstractList.java:343)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:353)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:279)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:326)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:52)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1214)
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.flush(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:986)
```

I have also found a related issue here: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-7537. Unfortunately, it seems that this issue has already been *CLOSED* with the solution marked as: *Cannot Reproduce*.

Has anyone else ever encountered this problem and found a way around it?

Comment: Is it reproducible? If so, I would submit a bug report to the Hibernate team and explain how to reproduce it.

Comment: Excatly so it reproducible, it's a pity, but I work for a bank and I can't share code, It's very difficult to emulate such situation, because in simple case it's work fine, but not in mine. I dont have another way rather than try to emulate it.

Comment: Can you experiment using different versions of Hibernate to see if it is a Hibernate issue (i.e. a buggy version of Hibernate) or whether the bug is on your application side?